# Trigger in SQL Server - Get the type of Transaction done for Audit Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I am writing trigger for inserting records into my `Audit` table.

Whenever there is a change in data in my target table, the trigger will update the old value, new value to the audit table

Additionally there are columns called `Transaction` and `Transaction_Status`

`Transaction` column defines the type of transaction. Can be `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.
`Transaction_Status` column indicates `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE`

How to achieve this ?

My trigger :

```
Alter Trigger TR_test
ON subscribers
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @OldValue xml,@NewValue xml, @changedby varchar(50), @ReferenceId int
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT @OldValue=b.username, @NewValue=a.username, 
       @ReferenceId = a.user_id, @changedby = a.modified_by
FROM inserted a, deleted b;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[audit_log]
           ([old_value],[new_value],[module],[reference_id],[transaction]
           ,[transaction_status],[stack_trace],[modified_on],[modified_by])
     VALUES
(@OldValue,@NewValue,'Subscriber',@ReferenceId,'_transaction',
'_transaction_status','_stack_trace',getdate(),555)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is a FOR UPDATE trigger. How are you going to capture INSERT and DELETE operations?

Comment: #Aaron Bertrand. So how can i achieve it ?

Comment: My point is your trigger says `FOR UPDATE`... needs to be `for update, insert, delete` if you want to capture all three actions.

Comment: #Aaron Bertrand, yeah, but how do i get Transaction_Status Col - Indicates SUCCESS or FAILURE ?

Comment: What do you mean by `Transaction_Status`. Do you intend to capture if the transaction will be committed (`SUCCESS`) or if it will be rolled back (`FAILURE`)?

Comment: #Mikael Eriksson, Yes i meant that. How can i check it ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You have a timing issue. The trigger happens before you can tell if the transaction will be rolled back or not and the data you save in your audit table will be rolled back as well. I think you need to build something outside the transaction in an exception handler or the likes.

Comment: @Mikael you can capture this with an instead of trigger, of course it requires a lot more work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hmm.. Do you mean the case when there is an implicit transaction for statement? In the case where the transaction spans multiple statements it is not possible right?

Comment: Well you can explicitly call a rollback in the catch. How that affects the outer transaction is up to the reader to determine. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, but if the update with the instead of trigger does just fine and a later update, in the same transaction, fails then you have already logged a success in the trigger but the changes will be rolled back including the audit logging in the trigger. I'll gladly admit my ignorance of how triggers work here, I don't use them...  at all :).

Comment: @Mikael I will show an example where an (implicit transaction) update or insert is rolled back, but the audit log remains.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson please check my updated answer and try it out. I did not spend any time on multi-statement explicit transactions - if they behave differently then obviously this won't be a solution.

Answer (score 8):

Once you fix your trigger to cover all three operations,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
  BEGIN
    SET @action = 'UPDATE';
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @action = 'INSERT';
  END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @action = 'DELETE';
END
```

Another alternative is three separate triggers, one for each action.

[Be wary of `MERGE`](https://sqlblog.org/merge) though if you are using it... Or be prepared for it when you move to SQL Server 2008 or beyond.

**EDIT**

I think what you may be after is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger instead (how ironic). Here is one example. Let's consider a very simple table with a PK column and a unique column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foobar(id INT PRIMARY KEY, x CHAR(1) UNIQUE);
GO
```

And a simple log table to catch activity:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.myLog
(
    foobar_id INT, 
    oldValue  XML, 
    newValue  XML, 
    [action]  CHAR(6), 
    success   BIT
);
GO
```

The following `INSTEAD OF` trigger will intercept `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` commands, attempt to replicate the work they would have done, and log whether it was a failure or success:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.foobar_inst
ON dbo.foobar
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
  DECLARE @action  CHAR(6), @success BIT;

  SELECT @action  = 'DELETE', @success = 1;
    
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
  BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
      SET @action = 'UPDATE';
    ELSE
      SET @action = 'INSERT';
  END
    
  BEGIN TRY
    IF @action = 'INSERT'
      INSERT dbo.foobar(id, x) SELECT id, x FROM inserted;
      
    IF @action = 'UPDATE'
      UPDATE f SET x = i.x FROM dbo.foobar AS f
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON f.id = i.id;
      
    IF @action = 'DELETE'
        DELETE f FROM dbo.foobar AS f
          INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON f.id = i.id;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK; -- key part here!

    SET @success = 0;
  END CATCH
          
  IF @action = 'INSERT'
    INSERT dbo.myLog SELECT i.id, NULL, 
      (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE id = i.id FOR XML PATH),
      @action, @success FROM inserted AS i;

  IF @action = 'UPDATE'
    INSERT dbo.myLog SELECT i.id, 
      (SELECT * FROM deleted  WHERE id = i.id FOR XML PATH),
      (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE id = i.id FOR XML PATH),
      @action, @success FROM inserted AS i;

  IF @action = 'DELETE'
    INSERT dbo.myLog SELECT d.id, 
      (SELECT * FROM deleted  WHERE id = d.id FOR XML PATH),
      NULL, @action, @success FROM deleted AS d;
END
GO
```

Let's try some very simple, implicit-transaction statements:

```
-- these succeed:

INSERT dbo.foobar SELECT 1, 'x';
GO
INSERT dbo.foobar SELECT 2, 'y';
GO

-- fails with PK violation:

INSERT dbo.foobar SELECT 1, 'z';
GO

-- fails with UQ violation:

UPDATE dbo.foobar SET x = 'y' WHERE id = 1;
GO
```

Check the log:

```
SELECT foobar_id, oldValue, newValue, action, success FROM dbo.myLog;
```

Results:

```
foobar_id oldValue                      newValue                      action success
--------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- ------ -------
1         NULL                          <row><id>1</id><x>x</x></row> INSERT 1
2         NULL                          <row><id>2</id><x>y</x></row> INSERT 1
1         NULL                          <row><id>1</id><x>z</x></row> INSERT 0
1         <row><id>1</id><x>x</x></row> <row><id>1</id><x>y</x></row> UPDATE 0
```

Of course you probably want other columns on the log table, such as user, date/time, maybe even the original statement. This wasn't meant to be a fully comprehensive auditing solution, just an example.

As Mikael points out, this relies on the fact that the outer batch is a single command that starts an implicit transaction. The behavior will have to be tested if the outer batch is an explicit, multi-statement transaction.

Also note that this does not capture "failure" in the case where, say, an UPDATE affects zero rows. So you need to explicitly define what "failure" means - in some cases you may need to build your own failure handling in the outer code, not in a trigger.

Comment: +1 and thanks. Needs a bit of testing to be used with multi-statement transactions and possibly some tests on @@trancount at that before rollback or commit in the outer transaction.

Comment: @Mikael yep, no warranty implied or intended, just a very simple POC.