# sqladaptor insert into different tables

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I want to create a function that can simultaneously update my old table and record the data that is before changed. (which is like a log table.) I created one table to retrieve the table I searched for and another one to store the table before changed.Those two table have some differences on the columns. 
DS is the retrieve dataset, ADS is the log dataset which only does insert

```
private void Update_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Update table1
            SqlCmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(SqlAd);
            SqlAd.Update(DS, "dataset1");

                //INSERT table1_log
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = ADS;
                ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("USER_NAME", typeof(string));
                ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("UNIQ", typeof(String));
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    dr["USER_NAME"] = Form1.USER_NAME.Text;
                    dr["ALTER_TIME"] = DateTime.Now;
                }
                SqlDataAdapter SqlAdI = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1_log where 0 = 1", SqlCon);
                SqlCommandBuilder SqlCmbI = new SqlCommandBuilder(SqlAdI);

                SqlCom= new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1_log FROM" + ds.Tables[0], SqlCon) ;
                SqlAdI.InsertCommand = SqlCom;
                SqlAdI.Update(ADS, "table1");


            MessageBox.Show("Info updated", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

My problem is it couldn't insert in the log table, updating into table1 works fine though. Uniq is the PK and autogenerate by the sql server. The error message is "Concurrency violation:the update command affected 0 of the expected 1 records."

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the ability to use libraries? If you can, check out dapper will make your life easier

Comment: Hi Konkked, what do you mean? I can successfully update to table 1 but not be able to insert into table_log, so I think I have the ability to use libraries.

Comment: @ericka08: You should look up triggers.  It is a good way to update a table when another table is updated.  You can add a trigger to a table, so that it will automatically update your log table automatically without the need for using a SQLCommand and keeping track of what changes where made in your code. We use these all the time at work to uddate log tables in the same way you are looking for.  I will try and find a link

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: @JSON I'm using datagridview and I hope I can stick on it. It makes my code very simple.I'll take a look, but that will be my last shot. Thank you!

Comment: @ericka Triggers work on the sql level and won't effect your c code at all.  You set it up as a stored procedure that automatically get called when an insert, update, delete, or what ever you pick occurs.  You can have different triggers called on different operations, so insert an delete operations on that table can call two different triggers.  Once you have your trigger established, you don't have to make call these manually on an update as they are automatically called when the update occurs.

Comment: @JSON Thanks! I am working on that. I will post the result I got later.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you should create a trigger. A trigger won't complicate your code or move you away from using DataGridView, it will actually make your code simpler (IMO, your code has several issues, but I will try to address the question). Triggers are implemented at the database level, not in your C# code. It will eliminate the need to write the insert statement explicitly in code, which will be especially helpful if you ever write multiple statements you need to log (such as insert, update, delete). You'll only have to write the insert to log statement a single time and it will always run.

I wonder if your issue with inserting is because your log table's primary key matches that of table1. In that case, a single record could be updated multiple times and attempt to use the same key, which would already be present in the log. The simplest fix would be to add a new primary key to the log table which would just be a sequential id that increments on each insert. I would recommend adding another column as well to indicate what type of operation is performed (i.e. insert, update, delete). Here is a good answer which explains how you would detect the operation: [Trigger in SQL Server - Get the type of Transaction done for Audit Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843817/trigger-in-sql-server-get-the-type-of-transaction-done-for-audit-table)

One more important point is that you are building an insert statement by concatenating strings. I'm not entirely sure where the value from ds.Tables[0] comes from, but you concatenate it directly into an insert statement which puts you at risk of a SQL injection attack if that is user input. An attacker could steal or delete data fairly easily. Even if it's checked somewhere else, I'd still recommend using a SqlParameter just so it's clear to anyone else who sees your code that you are protecting against these dangers.

Pseudo code for creating the trigger in sql:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TABLE1_AUDIT
ON table1
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
  -- your insert statement here
  INSERT INTO table1_log ...
```

Edit: Adding info about protecting against SQL injection attacks.
It doesn't matter how many fields you allow the user to enter, that isn't related to SQL injection attacks at all. To protect against it, you can't concatenate user input directly into the SQL statement. You need to do something like this:

```
// Set the command text (you could pass this in the constructor)
sqlcom.CommandText = "select * from table1 where loc = @loc ";
// Create SqlParameter
// Note that I don't know your actual SqlDbType, replace it with whatever it should be
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@loc", SqlDbType.Varchar) { Value = loc };
// Add to SqlCommand parameter collection
sqlcom.Parameters.Add(param);
// Add the command to your SqlDataAdapter if you are using one
```

This is called parameterization. Parameterizing anything the users input will protect you against SQL injection. You could do the SqlParameter inline with the Add statement to shorten things up.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I am working on creating a trigger now. For the primary key issue, I have created  a variable "UNIQ" to handle, which is different with the original one. For the sql injection issue, I only allow the users to input one variables into the sql. Looks like this: `select * from table1 where loc="+loc+"` Not sure if that can prevent sql injection, since I am very new to this.

Comment: I am a little confused about your claims with the primary keys. Primary keys are unique Identifiers that always have a 1 to 1 ratio with each row in the table.  If you are claiming that the tables primary keys are not 1 to 1, then it is by definition not a primary key.

Comment: @erickao08 I just edited my response to give more information on protecting against SQL injection

Comment: @JSON That is my point exactly, from what I understand the poster would like to use the same UID as primary key, which won't work since in a log/archive table, the same object could have multiple edit records. So an additional column should be added, called maybe log_id, that acts as the primary key. The uid of table1 is then added as a foreign key to the log table so you can see a history of changes to the record.

Comment: @JSON  and Brandon UNIQ is my log_id, which is 1 to 1. I created 2 dataset to store my table; however they're different. ADS is the log table which has  UNIQ as a the PK. DS has it's original PK so I'm not going to insert anything. The log table foreign key will be the PK of table 1.

Comment: @ericka08 That sounds right, but your comment is a little hard to understand... Is there a question in there?